# Extending LAN ports of a wifi router

Tags: wifi, local-area-network

I have a wifi router which has a built in LAN switch with two LAN ports. I have more than two devices which only support LAN connectivity, which I need to connect to my network.

Is it possible to connect a switch to one of the LAN ports of the router and connect my LAN only devices to this switch? If this is not possible, what else can I do?

Is only a single IP address assigned to a LAN port by the wifi router?

Comment: Vote to close based on Networking 101/lack of research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely possible and even it's a quite often practice. That network topology (called `star` btw) is used in almost every network.

Connecting a switch will not require additional IP addresses (assuming you won't use L3 switch). IP addresses will be required for the devices you're going to connect to your LAN (and respectively to the switch). Those IP addresses might be assigned to the devices by the router (if you have configured it that way).

Most SOHO (small office home office) routers have a DHCP enabled for their LAN Zone, so you should be fine. The router will assign as many addresses as configured to.

Comment: So, the wifi router does not assign a single IP to a LAN port, and multiple devices having own IP address can communicate with the router through a single LAN port. Am I correct? Previously I was thinking that a single LAN port can only have a single IP address, making it impossible for multiple devices to connect to router through a single LAN port.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Of course, if the devices are to communicate with each other in the same local network, they must have addresses from the same network.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using a switch will solve your problem.